# Return TABLE In FUNCTION Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to update some rows of my table while selecting and then return only updated rows. I used:

```
UPDATE RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO
```

It works correctly for updating rows, but when I use it in function for returning updated rows then an Oracle exception occurs.

Could you please explain why the first function works but the second doesn't work.

Here is the content of my table:

```
create table app.test (id number, col_to_update varchar2(20));

insert into app.test values (1, 'BOB');
insert into app.test values (2, 'PETER');
insert into app.test values (3, 'BOB');
insert into app.test values (4, 'PETER');
insert into app.test values (5, 'BOB');
```

Custom types:

```
create or replace type emp_dets as OBJECT (id INT,col_to_update VARCHAR2(60));
create or replace type emp_dets_nt as table of emp_dets;
```

And two functions:

```
create or replace function get_emp_dets
    return emp_dets_nt
as
    return_value emp_dets_nt;
BEGIN
    return_value:=emp_dets_nt(); 
    select emp_dets(ID, col_to_update)
    bulk collect into return_value
    from app.TEST;
    return return_value;
end;

create or replace function get_emp_dets
    return emp_dets_nt
as
    return_value emp_dets_nt;
BEGIN
return_value:=emp_dets_nt(); 
    UPDATE app.TEST
SET col_to_update = 'UPDATED'
WHERE col_to_update = 'BOB'
    RETURNING emp_dets(id, col_to_update)
    BULK COLLECT INTO return_value;
    return return_value;
end;
```

Comment: "then Oracle exception occurs" - what does the exception say? Please edit it into your question - thanks!

Comment: Hi, it says "Package or function GET_EMP_DETS is in an invalid state"

Comment: @SherifHuseynli - you can query the `user_errors` view to see what is actually wrong. Or after trying to compile, `show errors` is your client supports that. Also that seems to be two versions of the same function, not two functions? And all of that seems to compile OK, if run properly as separate statements.

Comment: @SherifHuseynli - works for me. If a function has compilation errors please include them in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using that function as pragma autonomous transaction

```
create or replace function get_emp_dets
    return emp_dets_nt
as
pragma autonomous_transaction;
    return_value emp_dets_nt;
BEGIN
return_value:=emp_dets_nt(); 
    UPDATE app.test
SET col_to_update = 'UPDATED'
WHERE col_to_update = 'BOB'
    RETURNING emp_dets(id, col_to_update)
    BULK COLLECT INTO return_value;
    commit;
    return return_value;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had added "pragma autonomous_transaction" and it worked for me too.